# Openlayer map not showing most of the time

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

Most of my target is Dubai. but later it will be applied to other countries. Map zoomin, zoomout and bottom text from openstreetmap is coming but map is not coming. sometimes it comes when I try to zoomin 2 times.

I am using this code

```
<style>
 .qvvenuemap {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
 }
</style>

<div class="qvvenuemap" id="venuemap"></div>

<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
function initvenue() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("venuemap");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 55.27 ,25.19 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
            map.getProjectionObject()
          );

    var zoom=18;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling your initvenue() function  ?

Comment: You have to call your initvenue function when your page is loaded and use https instead of http for get the OpenLayers.js library http url can be blocked by security. https://jsfiddle.net/mxe1n87a/

Comment: i am calling it from on click i have got 2 different functions

Comment: i added in one function and called from body onload still the maps are not coming

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your issue. Try to reproduce it on a snippet, with the code I tried on the jsFiddle is it working

Comment: in console i am getting this

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of null
    at initialize.adjustZoom (OpenLayers.js:185)
    at initialize.zoomTo (OpenLayers.js:195)
    at initialize.zoomIn (OpenLayers.js:197)
    at d.onZoomClick (OpenLayers.js:742)
    at initialize.triggerEvent (OpenLayers.js:138)
    at initialize.buttonClick (OpenLayers.js:146)
    at initialize.triggerEvent (OpenLayers.js:138)
    at initialize.handleBrowserEvent (OpenLayers.js:138)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (OpenLayers.js:63)

Comment: If it's intermittent it's probably an OSM server issue.  When using the OpenLayers example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/osm.html there does appear to be a problem at some zoom levels in the Dubai area.

Comment: i have also changed from http to https. Is it possible that localhost might be the problem

Comment: any suggestion which open source should I use for maps with marker

Comment: Take care at your naming too. Here you are using map without defining the var. It will used the glbal var map that he find (maybe on the OpenLayer script). I suggestion you to redefine a new variable `var myMap = new Open....`and replace `map.something` by `myMap.something` on the rest of your function

Comment: window.onload =  function(){ initvenue(); };

function initvenue() {
    var mymap = new OpenLayers.Map("venuemap");
    mymap.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 55.2778 ,25.1987 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
            mymap.getProjectionObject() 
          );
    var zoom=15;
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    mymap.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
    mymap.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
}